# Validate the .m3u8 file on linux

Tags: linux, http-live-streaming

I am new to HLS streaming. On MAC there is a mediastreamvalidator tool using which I can validate the .m3u8 file.

The question is how to do validate the same on Linux. I have looked around but have found no way.

Answer (score 5):

I found **HLS Checker Tool** by TSLemurs very good to validate HLS streams.
It is available for free here: http://www.tslemurs.com/ott/hls_checker_tool.html

It doesn't seem to support gzipped m3u8 files or http redirections, but it has been very useful to debug my m3u8 playlist format.